# In QFT, are there any restrictions on spontaneous breaking $G\to H$, due to "spontaneity"?

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, symmetry, field-theory, group-theory, symmetry-breaking

For simplicity, let us restrict to the spontaneous breaking of global symmetries. Given any pair of groups $G\supset H$, is it always possible to find a $G$-invariant Lagrangian that gives a QFT such that the vacuum state is only $H$-invariant?

For example, at least perturbatively at tree level,
$$\mathcal L=\frac12(\partial_\mu\phi^a)(\partial^\mu\phi^a)+\frac12m^2\phi^a\phi^a-\frac14\lambda\phi^a\phi^a\phi^b\phi^b,\quad a,b=1,\cdots,N$$
has a spontaneous $O(N)\to O(N-1)$ breaking. It has the familiar Mexican hat effective potential $V(\phi)$ (i.e., effective action for field configurations constant throughout spacetime). However, is it possible to modify the Lagrangian so that the vacuum only has an $O(N-2)$ symmetry? My guess is that we should introduce another $O(N)$-vector field and carefully setup the interactions, but after thinking for a couple of minutes I have got nothing... [If I later find a way to do this, I will leave a comment below.]

More generally, I wonder if there is a general strategy to construct a QFT with spontaneous $G\supset H$ breaking.

Any comment is welcome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For half a century, students have been going (running!) to [LF Li 1974](https://doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevD.9.1723) which also treats your problem as a warmup, a homework problem infiltrating lots of standard QFT texts like yours, apparently.

Two scalar fields,  which are O(*N*) vectors, will give you the generic O(*N*)-invariant potential (trash the disorienting superfluous pseudo-mass terms, for crying out loud!),
$$
\lambda (\vec\phi^2-v^2)^2 + \lambda' (\vec\chi^2-w^2)^2 +\lambda'' (\vec\phi \cdot \vec \chi-cvw)^2,
$$
where *c* is the cosine of the v.e.v. vectors, of lengths *v* and *w*, respectively.

You can see the minimum of the potential at its vanishing vanishing for these lengths and vanishing cosine (so the kinetic term need not be rediagonalized...). Of course, $c=1$ aligns the two vectors and gives you nothing new; but any other *c*  is in the domain of vanishing *c*, w.l.o.g. So, choose $\langle  \phi^i\rangle =v\delta_{1i}$,  $\langle  \chi^i\rangle=w\delta_{2i}$, hence their cosine vanishes, w.l.o.g.

The vanishing remaining components 3,...,*N* span an *N-2*-dimensional space, invariant under the unbroken O(*N*-2).

The strategy you are asking for is evident in the reference. You contrive potentials invariant under *G* with a minimum invariant under *H*, which the reference illustrates systematically for the standard classical Lie algebras/groups. I know of no inaccessible unbroken subgroup *H*.

Comment: Thanks for the nice answer! Indeed, it's much clearer to write the Lagrangian explicitly in terms of VEVs in perturbation theory. When I was asking the question, I was hung up on the idea of discovering possible symmetry breakings non-perturbatively from the Lagrangian, which apparently was asking too much. Also, your answer reminds me that $H$ is nothing but the stabilizer group of the VEV configuration, which explains why it's impossible to break $O(N)\to O(N-1)$ with just a single vector.